# Discrete random variables and probability models

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

During jury selection a large number of people are asked to be present, then persons are selected one by one in a random order until the required number of jurors has been chosen. Because the prosecution and defense teams can each reject a certain number of persons, and because some individuals may be exempted by the judge, the total number of persons selected before a full jury is found can be quite large.

(a) Suppose that you are one of 150 persons asked to be present for the selection of a jury. If it is necessary to select 40 persons in order to form the jury, what is the probability you are chosen?

(b) In a recent trial the numbers of men and women present for jury selection were 74 and 76. Let Y be the number of men picked for a jury of 12 persons. Give an expression for P (Y = y), assuming that men and women are equally likely to be picked.

(c) For the trial in part (b), the number of men selected turned out to be two. Find P (Y ≤ 2). What might you conclude from this?

I'm a little stuck on where to begin/which model to use, any tips? thanks!

Comment: This is a binomial process with fixed N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (a) Suppose that you are one of 150 persons asked to be present for the selection of a jury. If it is necessary to select 40 persons in order to form the jury, what is the probability you are chosen?

The *overly complicated method* is to count how to select yourself and 39 of the 149 other people out of all the ways to select 40 of 150 people.

$$\mathsf P(U) = {1\choose 1}{149\choose 39}\bigg/{150\choose 40} = \frac {\Box}{\Box}$$

There is a *much simpler* way to express this.  Fill in the boxes.

> (b) In a recent trial the numbers of men and women present for jury selection were 74 and 76. Let Y be the number of men picked for a jury of 12 persons. Give an expression for $\mathsf P (Y = y)$, assuming that men and women are equally likely to be picked.

However, here that method is best.  Count the ways to select $y$ of the men and *how many* of women out of all the ways to select 12 of 150 people.

$$\mathsf P(Y=y) = {\Box\choose \Box}{\Box\choose \Box}\bigg/{150\choose 12}$$

Fill in the boxes.

> (c) For the trial in part (b), the number of men selected turned out to be two. Find $\mathsf P (Y \leqslant 2)$. What might you conclude from this?

$$\mathsf P(Y\leq 2) = \mathsf P(Y=0) + \mathsf P(Y=1) + \mathsf P(Y=2)$$

Use the formula from part (b), evaluate, and comment.

Comment: I wish everyone commented the way you just did. Extremely helpful thanks a lot!